# Drizzle and Contract Instances

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle, contract-deployment

I am currently developing a dApp with Drizzle on top of ReactJS.

My project consists of, basically, 8 .sol files. 4 of them are just abstract contracts that include the functions, structs etc. for easier human readability and the other 4 hold the logic of the contracts.

My main issue is that some of the contracts must be unique to every user - The user should be able to create a new instance of a contract for as many times as they want.

I have tried to do it by having one more contract that will create the new instances, like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.10;

import './ContractToBeInstanced.sol';
contract newInstance {
  function newInstanceFunc(address _address) public returns(address) {
    ContractToBeInstanced T = new ContractToBeInstanced(_address);
    return T.getAddress(); //returns the address(this) of the contract
  }
}
```

and in the ContractToBeInstanced.sol I have a constructor that it sets the owner of the new instance:

```
  constructor(address _owner) public {
    owner = _owner;
    getAddress(); //it also calls the getAddress() to return the address to the parent function
  }
```

**So, my main issues are:**

- How do I create that instance through Drizzle? For example, I have tried:

```
<Button onClick={ () => this.contracts.newInstance.methods.newInstanceFunc.cacheSend(contractConfig.contractName, {from: this.currentAccount})) }>New Instance</Button>
```

Metamask opens, I run the transaction, it gets valid and then, nothing.
I also can not see the new (instance) of the contract in the **Contracts** menu in Ganache and there is no output in the transactions that returns the new contract's address. Is all this normal?

- When the new instance of the contract will be created, how will I be able to access it again in a later manner of time? I suspect that I will have to use some kind of IPFS or look through the past transactions? I know that this is a very simple question, but I am not really sure yet.

What I would also like to note, is that my truffle's migration files only do a:

```
deployer.deploy(ContractA).then( () => deployer.deploy(ContractB)...);
```

which I think is wrong and that the Migrations.sol is untouched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your factory contract, you can track the instances created.

```java
pragma solidity ^0.5.10;

import './ContractToBeInstanced.sol';
contract newInstance {

 mapping(address=>address) public userContracts;

  function newInstanceFunc(address _address) public returns(address) {
    ContractToBeInstanced T = new ContractToBeInstanced(_address);
    address deployedAddress = address(T);
    userContracts[_address] = deployedAddress;
    return deployedAddress;
  }
}
```

Edit: I have made an edit that could do away with the getAddress function in the ContractToBeInstantiated.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that may have the same problem, I followed Sanjay's answer and made some adjustments to it so it can fit **my** case better.

For the reason that I want users to have as many identities as they want (and name them), I needed a struct. So, I did this:

Created a struct which holds the:

- Address of the user
- Address of the instance
- The name that the user gave to the contract

Then, I created a mapping to correlate all this.
You can see the rest by reading the code below.

```
contract newInstance {

  struct someNewInstance {
    address usersAddress;
    address instanceAddress;
    string nameForTheInstance;
    bool instanceExists
  }

  mapping(address => mapping(bytes32 => someInstance)) public contractInstances;
  someInstance[] public listOfContracts;
  uint public instancesLength; //I use this to receive the number of the instances. Thus, I can loop and receive all the instances very easy!


  function createNewInstance(string memory _name) public returns(address) {
    bytes32 _id = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(msg.sender, _name));

    require(contractInstances[msg.sender][_id].instanceExists == false, "There is already an Identity with this name"); //Just checks

    theContractToBeInstanced newInstance = new theContractToBeInstanced(msg.sender);
    address instanceAddress = address(newInstance);

    someInstance memory newInstanceStruct = someInstance(msg.sender, deployedAddress, _name, true);
    listOfContracts.push(newInstanceStruct);

    contractInstances[msg.sender][_id] = newInstanceStruct;
    instancesLength++;

    return deployedAddress;
  }

}
```

It is possible that the code above needs some readjustment to be more efficient, but for now and for the testing that I am doing, it works.

Cheers =)